# How to retrieve a column value when part of that column's name is within part of another column's value in a separate table

Tags: dynamic, multiple-columns, selection

I am trying to load a column of product images depending on the part of the value of another column in a different table that specifies the "kit" value.

I have a table for images structured:
Product_code | Kit1 | Kit2 | Kit3 | Kit4
with values like:

Rose, http:URL1, http:URL2, http:URL3, http:URL4

PomPom, http:URL1, http:URL2, http:URL3, http:URL4

The other table is where product variations structured:
Product_Name | Color | Price
with values like:

Rose k1- holiday-123, Blue, 5.00

Rose k1- valentine-45, Red, 8.00

Rose k3- holiday-64, Blue, 5.00

Rose k2- valentine-32, Red, 8.00

I would like to select the content of the variations table and the image URL of the corresponding kit

Select `Variations`.*,
Select concat(`images`.,'Kit', substring(`Variations`.`Product_Name`,Instr(substring_index(`Variations`.`Product_Name`,'-',1),'k')+1,1)) where `Variations`.`Product_Name` like concat(`images`.`Product_cod`,'%')

in order to get

Rose k1- holiday-123, Blue, 5.00, http:URL1

Rose k1- valentine-45, Red, 8.00, http:URL1

Rose k3- holiday-64, Blue, 5.00, http:URL3

Rose k2- valentine-32, Red, 8.00, http:URL2

Thanks

Comment: If it's MySQL, please tag it accordingly.